# Position iframe to be above a footer section. Simple

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, styles

I would like an iframe to be above a footer section that has some content.

I am a real beginner at this, but I was able to scrap together some code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Test Layout</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body, html {
        margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
      }
      #footer {
        position:absolute; left: 0; 
        top: expression(document.body.clientHeight-150); 
        right: 0; 
        height: 150px; 
        background: red;
      }
      #content {
        position:absolute; 
        left: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        bottom: expression(document.body.clientHeight-150); 
        top: 0; 
        background: blue; 
        height: expression(document.body.clientHeight-150);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.link.com" />
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      Test content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

-The order is right, the iframe sits above, however the iframe itself is too small. I want there to be there is no scroll bar. The footer section doesn't show the background color or text. I've clearly made a mess of things.

-I also don't want the footer to be absolutely positioned, a user should scroll down a bit to see it.

-I am also curious to learn how to get rid of a scroll bar from an iframe even when the iframe is too small. Actually, it would be nice if there was a way to 'cut off' the bottom section of a source link and replace it with my footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oke first of - I would advise refraining from inline CSS and ID's it's 'better' practice to use a `CSS` file and link to it and rather using classes and for instance using footer tags for the footer etc. - But that's minor! don't worry about that, you can see on the fiddle bellow I took your example and put it into what I believe is what you wanted:

Edit: Updated jsFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/xuwd9/1/

I will add your code edited if need be :)

Comment: that's cool but I don't see the footer anywhere =(. It should have a red background and say test content.

Comment: I seriously don't see it. I tried scrolling down but it just reaches the end of the youtube vid. I think it's behind the youtube video. A difference in resolution maybe?

Comment: I tried to expand the bottom right corner window as big as it can go and I saw a bit of red background but no text.

Comment: What browser are you using? if checked multiple times and mine shows :/

Comment: You shouldn't expand the window - there is a scroll bar at the side of the bottom right window - or just hold over the video and scroll down

Comment: Hahaha I think I know what it might be (remeber overflow:hidden; takes scroll away) so try this link quickly: http://jsfiddle.net/xuwd9/2/ Otherwise just check that only the frame has overflow:hidden and not the body

Comment: same thing happens. I see a bit of red but no text. Does overflow: hidden really do that?

Comment: Jip - that causes the site to not show scroll bars and not be scroll able.

Comment: I can scroll through, but not in the iframe. In the corner window

Comment: Oke try this link: http://jsfiddle.net/xuwd9/1/embedded/result/ (it's the fullscreen version)